# Choose and plot lines in a structure

Tags: matlab, data-structures

Im having an issue specifying particular lines in a structure and plotting them.

I use `tblread` to take data from a file:

> table_data = tdfread(table,',');

The table has both numerical and text data, looks a bit like this:

protocol,num_nodes,scale_physical,density,trace,reliability

etx,50,4.7045454546,4.94,heavy,72.7

nh,50,3.8275862069,4.96,heavy,64.27

rtt,50,4.5454545455,5.12,heavy,50.44

etx,50,3.8275862069,4.88,light,93.33

nh,50,4.7272727273,4.94,light,82.45

The resultant data type is a `scalar structure` called `table_data`. I can plot each column against each other using:

```
scatter(table_data.scale, table_data.reliability)
```

What I would like to achieve is to plot specific elements in the columns defined by a value in another column. Eg. plot the scale vs reliability where protocol = "nh".

Essentially I would like to achieve this end result like:

> scatter(table_data.scale(table_data.protocol='nh'), table_data.reliability(table_data.protocol='nh'),'r')
>   hold on
>   scatter(table_data.scale(table_data.protocol='rtt'),table_data.reliability(table_data.protocol='rtt'),'b')

To differentiate the two types of points on the plot.

Is there any way of achieving this in a manor alluded to above.
Thanks.

EDIT:
solution is as follows:

```
 scatter(table_data.scale(table_data.protocol=='n'),table_data.reliability(table_data.protocol=='n'), 'r')
 hold on
 scatter(table_data.scale(table_data.protocol=='e'),table_data.reliability(table_data.protocol=='e'), 'b')
```

In the structure The text is held as array or characters rather than a cell. `table_data.protocol` then points only references the first character in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to replace the single equals in:

```
scatter(table_data.scale(table_data.protocol='nh'), table_data.reliability(table_data.protocol='nh'),'r')
```

to be a double equals like:

```
scatter(table_data.scale(table_data.protocol=='nh'), table_data.reliability(table_data.protocol=='nh'),'r')
```

i.e. you want a comparison operation instead of an assignment operation.